# my behavior subject displayed on the header does not refresh

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

On the header of my ecommerce, i display a behavior subject counter of the elements of my cart, this one is updated after every click of add to cart, but it doesn't display the new value, is that because the header is loaded one time?

header ngOnInit function :

```
ngOnInit() { 
  this.itemCount = this.shoppingCartService.countBS;
  ...
}
```

header Html :
    
        
         {{itemCount | async}}

Shopping Cart Service :

```
export class ShoppingCartService {
    ....
    public countBS: BehaviorSubject<number>;

public constructor() {
    ....
    this.countBS =  new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
}
```

Add items function :

```
private SetCount(quantity: number): void {
    this.count += quantity;
    this.countBS.next(this.count);
    this.storage.setItem('countCart', this.count.toString());
}
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: can you provide a minimal reproduction of your issue in stackblitz? there are a lot of missing elements in your question. For example: where/how do you call a function to increase the count? how are you providing the service?

Comment: I tried with your (partial) code and could not reproduce the issue, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dflxzt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html , so more details would be helpful.